# Cassandra : Is single table with 1 million counters better or 10 tables with 1 counters each?

Tags: cassandra, dashboard

I have a dashboard where I have to show a lot of distributions. To maintain all distributions, we need counters. Now I have two options

1. Maintain a single table with all 1 million counters (will be eventually many more - say millions or even more)
2. Maintain multiple tables to maintain different counters (Say 10 tables with 100 000 counters each)

I can achieve the same functionality using both options. But related to performance, which is better?

I am using Cassandra 1.2.10

Answer (score 1):

If the counters in the different tables have different workloads then you might get some benefit from separating them.  But if not, from a performance point of view there will be little benefit to separating them.  Having too many tables is detrimental to performance since the memtables will be flushed too often, creating more compaction work and more seeks on reads.

If there is some logical separation then it might be preferable to separate them because you could delete the whole table, whereas deleting some counters from a single table is much harder.  If e.g. there was a table per customer then you could delete a whole customer's counters should they request it.